# new Realm version for Xcode 7.3 / Swift 2.2 ? - "created by an older version"

Tags: realm

I wasn't paying attention and blindly said "*sure, stop hassling me and update the things*", but unfortunately that included Xcode, which is now at 7.3 with Swift 2.2.

Can I get a Realm somewhere that works with this?  I tried 0.98.5 but it gives this error for `import RealmSwift`:

> Module file was created by an older version of the compiler...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just run `carthage update` to get v0.98.6, now it works with Xcode 7.3